# How to always redirect from base / to specific path in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I want the base path `http://localhost:3000/` or `/` to redirect to `/wiki` in my app.

[image]

[image]

#### My app.routing.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CategoryComponent } from './category/category.component';
import { EntityComponent } from './entity/entity.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: '', redirectTo: '/wiki', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'wiki/category/:id', component: CategoryComponent },
            { path: 'wiki/entity/:id', component: EntityComponent }
        ])
    ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I assumed this was enough: `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/wiki', pathMatch: 'full' }`

Also tried `{ path: '/', redirectTo: '/wiki', pathMatch: 'full' }`

Anyone see what I'm missing?

---

I also tried adding the `HomeComponent` into the path for `/wiki`. Going to localhost:3000 still did not redirect to /wiki, and when I manually typed and went to /wiki I got the following error:

> Error: Invalid configuration of route '': redirectTo and component cannot be used together
>       at validateNode (/Users/leongaban/Projects/TickerTags/wikitags/dist/server/index.js:54088:15)
>       at Array.forEach (native)

Code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CategoryComponent } from './category/category.component';
import { EntityComponent } from './entity/entity.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: '', redirectTo: '/wiki', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'wiki/category/:id', component: CategoryComponent },
            { path: 'wiki/entity/:id', component: EntityComponent }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: It's enough but `/wiki` is no valid path in your configuration. You would need `/wiki/category/1` or similar

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer? Could you explain in a snippet? I already have a `wiki/category/:id` path. What I'm trying to force a redirect to `/wiki` if the base path to the app is hit.

Comment: What @GünterZöchbauer means is that you need a `{ path: '/wiki', component: WikiComponent }` in your routes

Comment: @YounesM oh I tried that too and it didn't work. It gives me this error: `Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route '': redirectTo and component cannot be used together`

Comment: Please show how that "tried that too" looked like.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer extra code added!

Comment: Your extra code contains a component for the `redirectTo` route, which doesn't make sense. You need a route that matches the redirect path so that the redirect can match another route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the redirect problem in the Node part of the app. Still will wait to see if there is a better Angular client fix for this.

I just added the path to `/` and redirected it to `/wiki`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return res.redirect('/wiki');
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var pojo = { status: 404, message: 'No Content' };
    var json = JSON.stringify(pojo, null, 2);
    res.status(404).send(json);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @GünterZöchbauer said, you need to define the path you'll redirect to. Here's a snippet.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CategoryComponent } from './category/category.component';
import { EntityComponent } from './entity/entity.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: '', redirectTo: '/wiki', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'wiki/category/:id', component: CategoryComponent },
            { path: 'wiki/entity/:id', component: EntityComponent },
            { path: '/wiki', component: HomeComponent }
        ])
    ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: The `/wiki` path should come last (order matters, and more specific paths should come first)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Shouldn't the empty path (path:'') come at last if we consider the order?

Comment: There is no conflict, especially with `pathMatch: 'full'`, but 3 paths starting with `wiki/...` conflicts and `wiki/category/...` or `wiki/entity/...` won't ever be reached. You also should remove the leading `/` before `path: '/wiki'`. Paths are not allowed to have leading `/` (it's fine for `redirectTo` though)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but still the same problem: `Listening on: http://localhost:3000
GET / 404 5.761 ms - 46` it hit's `/` but does not go to `/wiki` I also tried the recommended edits.

Comment: Btw I had to get rid of the `/` in front of that new `/wiki` path.